# .Net How does the CLR keep track of the execution of a program?

Tags: c#, clr, jit

I do not have a specific problem but I'm asking out of curiosity.

How does the CLR keep track of the execution state of a program?

Does the CLR have its own "loop"  and always loop through the bytecode and decide when JIT a method or when to call the jitted method?

If so, how? Let's say you have following methods

```
public void Foo()
{
   int a = 0;      
   bar(a);
}

public void bar(int a)
{
   Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Let's assume none of the methods is jitted yet.

Then method `foo()` is called, jitted to machine code and executed.

The machine code now calls `bar()`.

How does the CLR know that `bar()` wasn't jitted yet and needs to be jitted, if it is called on machine code level?

Comment: have a look : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/abhinaba/net-just-in-time-compilation-and-warming-up-your-system

Comment: Basically, all calls take place through a thunk, which can be thought of as a function pointer. Until the first time the function pointer is referenced, it points to a Compile This stub, which, when called the first time, JIT-compiles the code and updates the pointer to point to the result.